# regular expression in flutter dart

Tags: regex, string, flutter, dart, regular-language

I need help with removing all special characters, alphabets and numbers except nepali fonts from given string. I tried using RegExp class but the result isnot as desired.

```
ङ गर्नेगर्थे । सँधै छोराले स्कुल जाने काम साईकलमा गर्थ्यो । साईकल पार्किंगमा राखिन्थ्यो ।&lt;/span&gt;&lt;br&gt;&lt;/p&gt;&lt;p&gt;छोराले त्यसदिन प
नि त्यसैगरि राखेर कोठामा आयो । भोलीपल्ट बिहान स्कुल जाँदा पार्किंगमा साईकल देखिएन । चाबी लगाएर राखेको साईकल हरायो । छोरो हिंडेर स्कुल गयो ।&lt;/p&g
t;&lt;p&gt;बेलुकी फर्केपछि आमा र छोरा भएर पुलिसमा रिपोर्ट
";

String removeAllHtmlTags(String htmlText) {
    RegExp exp = RegExp(
        r"<[a-z]*>",
        multiLine: true,
        caseSensitive: true
    );

    return htmlText.replaceAll(exp, '');
  }
```

Comment: use html package and its parse function

Answer (score 1):

Use the [html](https://pub.dev/packages/html) package

```dart
import 'package:html/dom.dart';
import 'package:html/parser.dart';

String removeAllHtmlTags(String htmlText) {
    var document = parse(htmlText);
    return document.text;
  }
```